# Application works for me, but everyone else gets EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

My application works perfectly well for me, but crashes before even opening the main window for everyone else!

The only information I have (at the moment) is this...

```
Date/Time: 2011-02-06 13:32:26.599 -0500
OS Version: Mac OS X 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version: 6

Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread: 0

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: //CancelButtonPlugin.framework/Versions/A/CancelButtonPlugin
Referenced from: /Users/user/Downloads/Dash.app/Contents/MacOS/Dash
Reason: image not found

Binary Images:
0x7fff5fc00000 - 0x7fff5fc3bdef dyld 132.1 (???) <B536F2F1-9DF1-3B6C-1C2C-9075EA219A06> /usr/lib/dyld
```

Why am I getting this problem? What is "`EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)`" and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the system misses the library you promised it, in your case the C`ancelButtonPlugin.framework` one. Luckily, this is easy to solve, go to Xcode, and add a `Copy Files` build phase to your project. Destination is `Frameworks` and then drag'n'drop all your third party Frameworks into it. Recompile everything and you are done.

Comment: I already had that! It's already in a copy files build phase to the Frameworks folder. :(